# Initialize protected const in class constructor

Tags: c++, oop, initializer-list

I'm trying to accomplish a pretty simple thing: A protected const member of a class should be initialized (get a value) when an instance of the class is created, i.e. when calling the constructor. Something like this:

```
MyClass.hpp:
class MyClass {
public:
   //some methods

MyClass(){}    //Constructor
protected:
const int Variable;
};

MyClass.cpp: 

//some method definitions
MyClass::MyClass(int newVariable): Variable(newVariable) {} //constructor
```

I have experimented with `static`keywords and other stuff, each giving its own more or less enlightening compiler error. In the example the "copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted".

This is rather frustrating as everything was working fine until I started to protect members.

As a side note: If a `const` member cannot be modified once defined, is protection and writing getter/setter methods still necessary? It really does not speed up development...

**EDIT: Relevant Code:**

```
#ifndef Servo_hpp
#define Servo_hpp
#pragma once

class Servo{
  friend class Grid;
 public: 
    Servo(int newID, int newRow, int newCol);
    //Some other methods

const int row;

const int column;

const int number;

double currentAngle;

double nextAngle;

double currentSpeed;

const int ID;   //TODO: Change to new grid
};

#endif /* Servo_hpp */

Servo::Servo (int newID, int newRow, int newCol): ID(newID), column(newCol), row(newRow), currentAngle(0), currentSpeed(0), number(0){}
```

The last part is in the .cpp file

**Edit 2**

The problem occurs when I try to create a vector array of MyClass:

```
 std::vector<MyClass> MyClassArray;
     for (int Variable = 0; Variable < 5; Variable++) {
         MyClassArray.push_back(*new MyClass(Variable));
     }
 }
```

When I put this code together with the class definition from above, this complies fine with g++, but XCode gives the error "Object of Type 'MyClass' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted". I can understand the problem: One cannot assign a const member, but I do not copy a MyClass anywhere, do I?

Comment: So what is the actual problem?  The error message is pretty straight forward.  *copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted* this meas you cannot assign a `Myclass` to an already created `Myclass` as you cannot change `Variable`.

Comment: Thanks, the underlying problem is: Set `Variable` to one specific value when an instance of MyClass is created, then make sure this value remains the same for that instance as long as it lives

Comment: Okay.  So what code are you actually having a problem with.  If you want *make sure this value remains the same for that instance as long as it lives* then of course you cannot do `Myclass a{42}, b{50}; a = b;`

Comment: Where am I doing that? In the code using `MyClass` I want to do something like `MyClass a(1), MyClass b(2)`. As long as the objects `a` and `b` live, they should under all circumstances hold the 1 or 2, respectively as their `Variable`. The solution might look entirely different from what I have done, it's just my most recent trial.

Comment: So can you show the code that is giving the compiler error and mark which line it comes from?

Comment: You should post an [mcve] and clarify your question. It isn't even clear whet you're asking anymore.

Comment: Apparently the error actually comes from a different part of the code, which I have included in the second edit and makes much more sense for me.

Comment: `*new MyClass(Variable)` - never ever do that! You're leaking memory all over the place for no reason. Just do `push_back(MyClass(Variable))`.

Answer (score 1):

> In the example the "copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted".

Which makes perfect sense. An assignment is a mutating operation, and a `const` object (your data member) should be mutated. You have designed your class to be non-assignable.

Note that `protected` has no relevance here.

Note 2: if you want to be able to default construct your class, you need to initialize its data member in the default constructor:

```
MyClass(): Variable(42) {}
```

Comment: I'm not insisting on my idea. The task is to set `Variable` when an instance of `MyClass` is created and prevent this value to change as long as specific instance lives. Of course it can be different for other instances of MyClass

Comment: @chris1992 Right. Assignment changes an instance, so it is OK for assignment to be disallowed.